# How to remove the bootstrap5 tooltip from angular component.ts file on mouseover event?

Tags: bootstrap-5, angular13

I have added tooltip to div using bootstrap5.3 but on mouse out event tooltip is not hiding
please find my below code

```
 somefunction() {
 const rect = document.createElement('div');
      rect.style.position = 'absolute';
      
      rect.innerHTML = this.customService.htmlStr;
      rect.style.left = this.lastMousePosition.x + 20 + 'px';//(foundItem.rect.x2/this.viewPortScale) + 2 + 'px';
      rect.style.top = this.lastMousePosition.y + 20 +'px';//(foundItem.rect.y2/this.viewPortScale) + 2 + 'px';
      rect.setAttribute('annoId', foundItem?.annotationId + '');
      rect.setAttribute('data-bs-toggle', 'tooltip');
      rect.setAttribute('data-bs-placement', 'right');
      rect.setAttribute('title', 'Click to Unmask');
      path.find((p: any) => p.className === 'page').children[2].appendChild(rect);
      rect.addEventListener('mouseover', (event: any) => {
        let ids = event.target.id;
        new bootstrap.Tooltip(rect).show();
      });
      rect.addEventListener('mouseover', (event: any) => {
        let ids = event.target.id;
        console.log('mouseover');
        new bootstrap.Tooltip(rect).disable();
        new bootstrap.Tooltip(rect).dispose();
      });
}



ngOnInit(): void {
   
    var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'));
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map( function(tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl);
});
    this.getCurrentStudy = sessionStorage.getItem('studyID');
    this.getUploadedDoc();
    this.getAllCategories();
    // this.PIIData()
  }
```